# error in converting linked list to a single number in python

Tags: python, list, numbers

here this is the node definition

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self,value=None):
       self.value = value
       self.next = None
```

this is the conversion for the code a number to linked list

```
def number_to_list(number):
    head,tail = None,None
    p = True
    for x in str(number):
        if x=='-':
            p = False
            continue
        else:
            if p:
                node = Node(int(x))
            else:
                node = Node(int("-"+x))
        if head:
            tail.next = node
        else:
            head = node
        tail = node
    return head
    pass
```

this is code for conversion of linked list to number

```
 def list_to_number(head):
    neg = False
    num = ''
    for number in head:
        val = str(number)
        if (val.find('-')!= -1):
            neg = True
        num=num+val.replace('-','')
    if (neg==False):
        return int(num)
    else:
        return -1*int(num)
    pass
```

here it is the test cases

```
def test_number_to_list():
    import listutils

    head = number_to_list(120)
    assert [1,2,0] == listutils.from_linked_list(head)
    assert 120 == list_to_number(head)

    head = number_to_list(0)
    assert [0] == listutils.from_linked_list(head)
    assert 0 == list_to_number(head)

    head = number_to_list(-120)
    assert [-1, -2, 0] == listutils.from_linked_list(head)
    assert -120 == list_to_number(head)
```

here from_linked_list means

```
 # avoids infinite loops
 def from_linked_list(head):
    result = []
    counter = 0
    while head and counter < 100: # tests don't use more than 100 nodes, so bail if you loop 100 times.
        result.append(head.value)
        head = head.next
        counter += 1
    return result
```

at last in this the problem is while converting the linked list to single number it is encountering an error i.e.,node object is not iterable

please help me out of this to write the code

```
def list_to_number(head):
    neg = False
    num = ''
   for number in  head:
        val = str(number)
       TypeError: 'Node' object is not iterable
```

here this is the traceback

Comment: Please include the exact traceback as well

Comment: i edited my traceback in the code please check it and help me to write the code @user3387584

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

```
for number in head:
```

is not a correct way to iterate of the list.

You need to start from `head` and then follow the chain of `next` references.

Comment: then how should i do please tell me i have strucked in this since two days please help me out of this @NPE

Comment: sorry for asking can you give me an example to do this @NPE

Comment: i have tried so far.can you please help me how to write the code? @NPE

Comment: how to follow a chain please tell me to do this?

Comment: def list_to_number(head):
        p = True
        num = ''
        if head == '-':
            p = False
        while head:
            val = str(head)
            num = num+val.replace('-','')
            head = head.next
        if p == False:
            return -1*num
        else:
            return num
        pass but it is giving assertion error

Answer (score 0):

Note that if `__iter__` is defined on `Node` like this:

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self,value=None):
       self.value = value
       self.next = None

    def __iter__(self):
        that = self
        while that is not None:
            yield that.value
            that = that.next
```

Then:

```
for number in head:
```

Would actually work.